# Changing elements in selected UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have implemented a custom UITableViewCell for my application and have created a custom background view and selectedbackgroundview, both of which work great. However, I have several other images and uilabels on the cell that I want to change the color's of when it is selected. I have overwritten the following method and it logs correctly when the cell is selected but it does not change the image or the text color.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {
        NSLog(@"setSelected:YES");
        separatorImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SeparatorSelected"];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"setSelected:NO");
        separatorImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Separator"];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
}
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Update

```
separatorImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Separator"]]];
[separatorImage setFrame:CGRectMake(99, 4, 5, 71)];
separatorImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:separatorImage];

titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(111, 4, 188, 26)];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:21.0];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
```

Comment: Have you tried tossing a `[self setNeedsDisplay];` call at the end of your method?

Comment: Yeah I did try that, but I removed it because it did nothing.

Comment: How are `separatorImage` and `titleLabel` defined?

Comment: I added those, but they should not be the problem because the initial values show just as I expect them to - I just cannot change them when highlighted/selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a hunch that sending `-setSelected:animated:` to `super` at the beginning of the method is preventing the changes to your cell. Try moving the call to `super` to the end of the method. You should also override `-setHighlighted:animated:` or your selection will appear to lag.

Comment: It turned out that I just needed to move the super call to the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: >>>>>> BOSS MOVE <<<<<